# Image classification - how to make my results clearer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The Python code uses Tensor Flow and Keras to classify images of cars. 0 = not a car. 1 = a car. I am a bit confused about the results. My data set contains 1513 jpg images.The results don't seem to show 1513 readings? Furthermore, the results are not in order. For example the results go "0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 " When in Reality, the first 10 images should all be '1' as the first 10 images are all cars.

Is there something I can do to make my results clearer? Kind regards.

```
from keras.models import Sequential # Initialise our neural network model as a sequential network
from keras.layers import Conv2D # Convolution operation
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D # Maxpooling function
from keras.layers import Flatten # Converting 2D arrays into a 1D linear vector.
from keras.layers import Dense # Perform the full connection of the neural network
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from skimage import io, transform
```

```
def cnn_classifier():
    cnn = Sequential()
    cnn.add(Conv2D(8, (3,3), input_shape = (50, 50, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
    cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    cnn.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding='same', activation = 'relu'))
    cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    cnn.add(Flatten())
    cnn.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
    cnn.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
    cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    print(cnn.summary())
    return cnn

def reshaped_image(image):
    return transform.resize(image,(50,50,3)) # (cols (width), rows (height)) and don't use np.resize()

def load_images_from_folder():
    Images = os.listdir("./Dataset/")
    train_images = []
    train_labels = []
    for image in Images:
            if image[-4:] == 'jpeg':
                path = os.path.join("./Dataset/", image)
                img = cv2.imread(path)
                train_images.append(reshaped_image(img))
                label_file = image[:-5] + '.txt'
                with open("./Dataset"+"/"+label_file) as f:
                    content = f.readlines()
                    label = int(float(content[0]))
                    l = [0, 0]
                    l[label] = 1 # 1=car and 0=not car
                    train_labels.append(l)
    return np.array(train_images), np.array(train_labels)

def train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, fraction):
    index = int(len(train_data)*fraction)
    return train_data[:index], train_labels[:index], train_data[index:], train_labels[index:]

train_data, train_labels = load_images_from_folder()
fraction = 0.8
train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, fraction)
print ("Train data size: ", len(train_data))
print ("Test data size: ", len(test_data))

cnn = cnn_classifier()

print ("Train data shape: ", train_data.shape)
print ("Test data shape: ", train_labels.shape)

idx = np.random.permutation(train_data.shape[0])
cnn.fit(train_data[idx], train_labels[idx], epochs = 10)
predicted_test_labels = np.argmax(cnn.predict(test_data), axis=1)
test_labels = np.argmax(test_labels, axis=1)

print ("Actual test labels:", test_labels)
print ("Predicted test labels:", predicted_test_labels)

print ("Accuracy score:", accuracy_score(test_labels, predicted_test_labels))
```

**RESULTS**

```
Train data size:  1210
Test data size:  303
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 50, 50, 8)         224       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 25, 25, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 25, 25, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_10 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 2704)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 128)               346240    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================
Total params: 347,890
Trainable params: 347,890
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train data shape:  (1210, 50, 50, 3)
Test data shape:  (1210, 2)
Epoch 1/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 1s 433us/step - loss: 0.4682 - accuracy: 0.8331
Epoch 2/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 300us/step - loss: 0.2686 - accuracy: 0.9066
Epoch 3/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 320us/step - loss: 0.1746 - accuracy: 0.9421
Epoch 4/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 302us/step - loss: 0.1177 - accuracy: 0.9595
Epoch 5/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 311us/step - loss: 0.1105 - accuracy: 0.9620
Epoch 6/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 298us/step - loss: 0.1019 - accuracy: 0.9645
Epoch 7/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 302us/step - loss: 0.0695 - accuracy: 0.9752
Epoch 8/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 309us/step - loss: 0.0672 - accuracy: 0.9777
Epoch 9/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 295us/step - loss: 0.0503 - accuracy: 0.9826
Epoch 10/10
1210/1210 [==============================] - 0s 304us/step - loss: 0.0348 - accuracy: 0.9893
Actual test labels: [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Predicted test labels: [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Accuracy score: 0.9405940594059405
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you are trying to do binary classification with one hot matrix for the label. compile your model using `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy` because your label in one hot form.

For better model, I suggest you to change the last layer using `1` neuron and use `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` for binary classification, and you can use `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function.

you can read [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/loss-and-loss-functions-for-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) for more detail info